# Trouble using thumbnail helper Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, thumbnails

Currently using Fancybox to display lightbox galleries on this [prototype](http://mtthwbsh.com/sta499)

I'm using the following jQuery when triggering Fancybox (which includes the thumbnail helper) but can't get them to display. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "image",
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            },
            buttons: {},
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            this.title = '' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you know that you have also to include the fancybox-thumbs .js and .css files? like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
```

.... (check you set your own correct path) otherwise you will never make them work.

They are under the subdirectory `helpers/` of the download.

Comment: Heh, wow, thought that was included in the minified version of Fancybox. I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: This had me confused too - totally missed the additional files for thumbs and buttons! Neither will work unless the helper files are included with the main fancybox includes!